# res.cookie() doesn't after connection with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, cookies, express

I tried to connect to mysql database, run a query then set a cookie only if password was correct (I know I shouldn't be using md5, this is just a test project). This is the code I've written, when I execute and make a request to this request, it says `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

but I've not sent any response till I'm calling `res.cookie()` I don't know what's wrong:

```
    email=req.params.email;
    password=req.params.password;
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : 'nishchal11',
      database : 'venturesity'
    });

    connection.connect();
    sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email="+connection.escape(email)+" AND password=md5("+connection.escape(password)+");";

    connection.query(sql,function (err,rows,fields) {
        res.cookie("email",email);
        if(!err){
            if(rows.length==1){
                //res.cookie("password",rows[0].pass);
                console.log(rows[0].pass);
            }else{
                console.log("wrong pass");
            }
        }else{
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
    res.end(sql);
```

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Is there some earlier executing piece of code which sends content? You also need to place string delimiters (i.e. single quotes) around the string values in the query and you really should think about closing your SQL injection vulnerability.  You already noted that you password hashing approach is not sound - you are correct about that.

Comment: connection.escape escapes the sql injection, and I'm not really worried about that now because as I've mentioned this is just a testing phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ending the response early (`res.end(sql)`), before the query gets executed (the query is async). Remove that and instead end the response inside the query callback and the error should go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew that, what a dumb mistake :D